# Error using ObjectStream to send SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-sqlite, objectoutputstream

I'm using ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream to send an object. I'm trying to send an SQLiteDatabase but I'm getting an error when doing so.

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; 
java.io.NotSerializableException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
```

I've tried searching but haven't really been able to find a solution. Thanks

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: I just wasn't sure if there was a way to serialize the object or something. I understood the error message, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot serialize arbitrary objects. Among those that you cannot serialize is a `SQLiteDatabase`. This is why you are getting a `NotSerializableException` — that object is `Not` `Serializable`.